# Carthage setup fails with code 65

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json, carthage

I'm installing carthage on a new machine.

`$ brew install Carthage`

`[in project root] $ emacs Cartfile`

```
# Alamofire
github "Alamofire/Alamofire"

# SwifyJSON
github "SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON"
```

`$ carthage update`

```
*** Fetching SwiftyJSON
*** Fetching Alamofire
*** Checking out Alamofire at "1.2.3"
*** Checking out SwiftyJSON at "2.2.0"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/8n/044rh7_j6nlcdtsb3cgp_snc0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.log
*** Building scheme "Alamofire iOS" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
A shell task failed with exit code 65:
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal x86_64 [project root]/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/Request.swift
    CompileSwift normal x86_64 [project root]/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/ResponseSerialization.swift
    CompileSwift normal x86_64 [project root]/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/Manager.swift
    CompileSwift normal x86_64 [project root]/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/Alamofire.swift
    CompileSwift normal x86_64 [project root]/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/Source/Validation.swift
    CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
```

(6 failures)

Answer (score 1):

```
 Building scheme "Alamofire iOS" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
```

for get before version write this to carthage

```
github "Alamofire/Alamofire" >= 4.2.0
```

see [realese](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/releases) project in github for select version for your swift version

also you can select platform when run carthage
example

```
carthage update --platform iOS
```